# React Datepicker How to format date from string

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

my goal is simple, displaying a date from database in react datepicker. From my database, I got the string `"2019/10/26 15:05"`, but when setting it as `selected` it returned,

> Starting with v2.0.0-beta.1 date-fns doesn't accept strings as
>   arguments. Please use `parseISO` to parse strings

```
<DatePicker
dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
showTimeSelect
timeFormat="HH:mm"
timeIntervals={1}
selectsEnd
startDate={this.state.beginDate}
endDate={this.state.endDate}
selected={this.state.endDate}
onChange={this.selectEndDate} />
```

I also tried `date-fns`'s `parseISO` but it's still not working. what should I do?

Comment: How, exactly, did you try `parseISO`? You should be able to write `selected={parseISO(this.state.endDate)}` etc. Or better, use parseISO when setting state in the first place to keep things consistent with `selectEndDate`, which receives a `Date` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
Date.parse(this.state.endDate)
```

makes it work for me

Answer (score 0):

```js
const datePickerToString = (picker) => {
  if (!picker) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    const currentDate = new Date().toISOString();
    const currentSub = currentDate.substring(10);
    //
    const pickerDate = new Date(picker);
    const day = pickerDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0");
    const month = (pickerDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0");
    const year = pickerDate.getFullYear();
    const pickedCustom = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    //
    const returnDate = pickedCustom + currentSub;
    return returnDate;
  }
};
    
    // Date selected 05/12/2023
    // get value
      console.log(datePickerToString("Tue Nov 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)")); // 2023-12-05T19:25:50.893Z with local  Date time
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
handleChange =(selectedDate) =>{
    var selectedDateStr = moment(selectedDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
    this.props.input.onChange(selectedDateStr);
}

render() {
    const { input, meta: { touched, error, active } } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <DatePicker
                {...input}
                className="datepicker form-control"
                peekNextMonth
                showMonthDropdown
                onChange={selectedDate => this.handleChange(selectedDate)}
                dateFormat="dd.MM.yyyy"
                showYearDropdown
                dropdownMode="select"
            />
            {touched && (!active && error &&
                <div className="invalid-feedback d-block position-absolute">
                    test
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```